# MS Azure Botframework extract data from conversation

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing a chatbot using Botframework with NodeJs. I'm also using QnA maker and for future implementation I want to use LUIS.
So, is it possible to extract relevant information from the conversation like ansewer typed by the user and question from the bot ? I was wandering about using CosmosDB in order to store these info and then use it to instantiate a new ML Model or simply use it for analytics purpose.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of these things are possible.

In Node.js, messages are exchanged between the user and the bot using a session object.

In particular,

```
var userMessage = session.message.text;
```

[This blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/09/28/qna-maker-revisited-suggested-actions-app-insights/) is for .NET, but showcases how to store a user's question, along with a QnA answer and their feedback and save that data to an Azure database, CosmosDB/Table Storage can easily be done with this.

[This one](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/11/17/qna-maker-node-js-bots/) provides some insight how you can use QnA with a node.js bot. Answers from the QnA service are similarly handled via a session object,

```
basicQnAMakerDialog.respondFromQnAMakerResult = function(session, qnaMakerResult){
// Save the question
var question = session.message.text;
session.conversationData.userQuestion = question;

// save answer from QnA 
var qnaAnswer = qnaMakerResult.answers[0].answer;
```

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I tried add these lines of code in my app.js file and it not give me error but when I simulate a conversation in the emulator I'm not able to produce any answer for the question. How I can manage it?
I also tried to follow the link but it's not so helpful

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you can leverage the middeware feature in bot framework to catch each message the bot receives from users and each message the bot sends to users.

In middeware functions, you can directly handle the messages.

The code snippet should be like:

```
bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        console.log('message: ' + event.text + ', user: ' + event.address.user.name);
        //TODO
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        console.log('message: ' + event.text + ', user: ' + event.address.user.name);
        //TODO
        next();
    }
})
```

You can refer to the official sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/capability-middlewareLogging/app.js for reference.